# asp.net mvc modifying master file from a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I need to add class attribute to the body tag from a view file (.aspx), but the  tag is in the master file. How can I access the body tag from a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view output you could just add a [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) client script to do it which will run once your page is pieced together:

```
$('body').addClass('yourClass');
```

Another method would be to store the class data in your controller like:

```
ViewData["MasterPageBodyClass"] = "yourClass";
```

Then in your `MasterPage` view you could check for the existance of this and add it if it exists:

```
<%
    string bodyClass = "";
    if (ViewData["MasterPageBodyClass"] != null)
    {
        bodyClass = "class=\"" + ViewData["MasterPageBodyClass"].ToString() + "\"";
    }
%>
<body <%= bodyClass %>>
```

Only the controller actions that required the class to be attached to the body would actually need to store the class in the `ViewData` every other action could just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

think a simpler solution is just set a placeholder at the master for the class attribute:

```
<body class='someOtherClass <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="BodyCssOverrides" runat="server" />' >
```

then in your views just set the proper class:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="BodyCssOverrides" runat="server">yourBodyClass</asp:Content>
```

no need for scripts to set it or ViewData.

remember that the masterPage is a template that should help you and not get in your way,
if something needs to change between views - make a placeHolder for it